# Regex C# - optional group in the middle

Tags: c#, regex

I have such source text with an optional group in the middle:

```
GH22-O0-TFS-SFSD 00-1-006.19135
GH22-O0-TFS-SFSD 00-1-006.1.19135
```

Desired value in the first case will be '19135' and in the second '1.19135'.

Regex has to match the whole string and select all characters after first "." - which is my Group 1. I tried to make subgroups and mark Group 3 as optional but it is not working.

Regex:

```
.*\.0*(([0-9])(\.0*([0-9]+)))
```

How it should be changed to capture desired values?

Comment: Get everything after the first period?  https://regexr.com/3elkd

Comment: The proposed solution is not ok because as I mentioned: regex should match the whole text and select values as a group.

Comment: You seem to need anchors, lazy dot pattern at the start and an optional non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
.*?\.(.*)
```

This will match the whole string and include everything after the first period in capture group 1 regardless of character type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
^(.*?)\.0*(\d+)(?:\.0*(\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/163B9u/6). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than an LF char as few as possoble (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `\.` - a dot
- `0*` - zero or more zeros
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: any one or more digits
- `(?:\.0*(\d+))?` - an optional occurrence of `.`, zero or more zeros, then Group 3 capturing one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your goals and this should work:

```regex
.*?\.([\d.]+)
```

- `.*?\.` - loosely capture everything leading up to the first period
- `([\d.]+)` - capture the remaining digits and periods into capture group #1

https://regex101.com/r/0t9Ijy/1